# Storing SSL socket connection for reusability Python

Tags: python, sockets, imapclient

I am using IMAPClient library for fetching emails.
In my application i have multiple options where i have to always create a socket connection or login to email account using IMAPClient.

1. Read mail
2. Fetch mail
3. Fetch folders
   etc

For each options my application has to create a connection with email account using  `IMAPClient` which consume time.
Is there any way where i can only create a connection one time and same connection i can reuse to perform other activities whenever required.

Sample code example

```py
from imapclient import IMAPClient
email_address = "emailid"
password = "password"
imap_server = 'imap.gmail.com'
mail_server = IMAPClient(imap_server, use_uid=True, ssl=True)
mail_server.login(email_address, password)
```

I want to store this `mail_server` ssl socket object and reuse whenever needed.

Comment: Please share your code, or a relevant example, so people can suggest concrete changes. Don't ask StackOverflow to write your code for you.

Comment: question edited and code added

Comment: Other than referencing it with a variable (like you already have) , there's no way to "store" an ssl socket connection. That's like asking how to save a phone conversation, so you can start talking to the person on the other side whenever you like - you'll need to call them again / reconnect to the server. But as long as your script is running, you can use the connection in `mail_server`